# CSS - change link color on rollover of the div that contains it

Tags: css

```
<div class="positions">
<div class="main" style="clear: both;">
<div class="mainC">
<a class="news" href="#"><img src="salad.jpg" width="105" alt="salad"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="foot" style="clear: both;">
<h1 class="news"><a href="#">Salad</a></h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the color of the "Salad" link, when the parent "positions" div is rolled over? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: thought my eyes were failing me there for a second, then i noticed you're asking a question in Italian :)

Comment: @AndresIlich Google Translate FTW!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Css psuedo class `:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp):

```
.positions:hover h1.news a
{
  color:red;
}
```

[**-- SEE EXAMPLE --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/4Jx3p/)